# EditText - Translate like a drag operation inside FrameLayout for API < 11

Tags: android, draggable, android-edittext

I would like to translate `EditText` inside the FrameLayout through a drag operation, same as we can do for `ImageView` using `Matrix`.

I tried

- Same as onTouch() but as `ImageView` can use `Matrix` for `Translation`. We can't have tht option in `EditText`.

Is it possible to `drag` the `EditText` inside `FrameLayout`??

Comment: Hi Have you go through this library https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java it might helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

```
option1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_1);
    option2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_2);
    option3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_3);

    //views to drop onto
    choice1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_1);
    choice2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_2);
    choice3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_3);

    //set touch listeners
    option1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    option2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    option3.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    choice1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    choice2.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    choice3.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());

    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            /*
             * Drag details: we only need default behavior
             * - clip data could be set to pass data as part of drag
             * - shadow can be tailored
             */
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            //start dragging the item touched
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} 

/**
 * DragListener will handle dragged views being dropped on the drop area
 * - only the drop action will have processing added to it as we are not
 * - amending the default behavior for other parts of the drag process
 *
 */
private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //view dragged item is being dropped on
            TextView dropTarget = (TextView) v;
            //view being dragged and dropped
            TextView dropped = (TextView) view;
            //update the text in the target view to reflect the data being dropped
            dropTarget.setText(dropped.getText());
            //make it bold to highlight the fact that an item has been dropped
            dropTarget.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            //if an item has already been dropped here, there will be a tag
            Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();
            //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
            if(tag!=null)
            {
                //the tag is the view id already dropped here
                int existingID = (Integer)tag;
                //set the original view visible again
                findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //set the tag in the target view being dropped on - to the ID of the view being dropped
            dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

for more details refer to this [drag and drop](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality/)

Comment: Appreciated!! But I'm trying to achieve Drag in `Api < 11` So your reply won't work with it.

Comment: owh i didn't catch that. sorry!.